# Groovy - Problem with nested closure delegation

Tags: groovy, delegates, closures

I understand that Delegation works with owner first by default, else it takes the specific delegation. I cannot understand how the nested closure delegation works.
My Example:

```
class App1 {
String bar = "App1"
}

class App2 {
Closure c1 = {
    String bar = "App2"
    println("Closure 1 - $bar")
    Closure c2 = {
        println("Closure2 - $bar")
    }
    c2.delegate = new App1()
    c2.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    c2()
  }
}

App2 app2 = new App2() 
App1 app1 = new App1()

app2.c1.delegate = app1
app2.c1() 
println("***************")

app2.c1.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY // Delegation strictly to 
app2.c1()
```

Folowing is the result

```
Closure 1 - App2
Closure2 - App2
***************
Closure 1 - App2
Closure2 - App2
```

The thing that doesn't make sense to me is with the last line printed. Even after delegating Closure c2 to App1 with DELEGATE_ONLY, why is it considering bar = "App2"?!

Answer (score 1):

It's picking up `bar` as the local variable `bar`, it's not having to look at the delegate at all to resolve it, so everything is `App2`

If you move it outside of the closure in app2:

```
class App2 {
    String bar = "App2"
    Closure c1 = {
        println("Closure 1 - $bar")
        Closure c2 = {
            println("Closure2 - $bar")
        }
        c2.delegate = new App1()
        c2.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        c2()
    }
}
```

You get the output

```
Closure 1 - App2
Closure2 - App1
***************
Closure 1 - App1
Closure2 - App1
```

Comment: Okay. When I print the owner of Closure c2, it gives `App2$_closure1@25084a1e`. So it's using the owner's (App2's) `bar`. So if I delegate it to `App1`, shouldn't it consider the delegated class's (App1's) `bar`?
Or is it that I have understood delegation completely wrong?